# How can failure of Class Y capacitors lead to electric shock?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, ac, safety, emi-filtering

This [article](https://www.powerelectronictips.com/x-and-y-safety-capacitor-applications-virtual-roundtable-part-1-of-2/) mentions "Due to the fact that equipment cases are usually grounded, Y caps require higher safety to avoid risks of electrical shocks to users"
[image]

1. How can an equipment with chassis grounded cause electric shock?

- Even if Y capacitor shorts to GND (Fig 1), wouldn't the protective earth connection offer lower resistance than human body (Similar to Fig 2)

2. For a grid connected power supply, isn't neutral always grounded near distribution transformer- Then do we still need the  Y capacitor for Neutral line?

Comment: I guess it's not something you 100% want to rely on to prevent shock if you don't have to. After all, failing open surely is better in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In an ideal world a Y-Capacitor failing short would trip a safety device, either a fuse or a GFCI will trip.

Sadly, your world is not ideal and a ground path has a lot of ways to be broken.
It's a chain of connections and a fault in a single one of them will break your earth connection. In normal operation you'll not notice that anything is wrong with your earth connection!

- The connection inside the device between the case and the earth conductor of the cable (or the connector at the device)
- The device cable itself could have a broken earth connection
- The pin in the wall plug could be corroded, worn out or just disconnected
- The conductor in the wall could be broken
- The earth connection could be on a bad or corroded clamp in a junction box
- The connection from your electrical panel to earth could be bad because of a loose screw terminal or corrosion
- The chosen earth path could be too high impedance

And if only a single one of those cases is true, your device won't be correctly grounded anymore. I think in light of the fact that we can't guarantee a good earth connection all the time it's good to have an additional safety built in.

Answer (score 8):

It would potentially lead into hazardous situations if an Y capacitor would fail into a short circuit.

However, Y capacitors are special safety capacitors that are specifically designed to fail into an open circuit to prevent hazardous situations.

And Y capacitors are also used on ungrounded equipment. If an Y capacitor would fail short in for example a mobile phone charger, the USB cable and phone metal parts would be live with rectified mains.

1. You can plug a grounded device into ungrouded socket, or have a broken wiring, where only live ends up into device, and thus you have an ungrounded device with Y cap between live and metal chassis. Y caps are also used in ungrounded devices between mains side and low voltage side such as mobile phone chargers so there is no ground at all.
2. Yes also the neutral does need the cap. The point is to filter common mode noise at the device, so both live and neutral need Y caps to earth, or it won't filter. You can also plug in mains plug in any orientation or someone might have messed the wiring so you also don't know which wire going into device is live or neutral so you would not know to which wire to put a single cap.

Comment: Also, there are braindead systems like the german Schuko (Type F) or the Italian (Type L) that have symmetrical plugs that can be plugged in in two directions so you never know where phase and where neutral is in a device.

Comment: @kruemi That's just your opinion and this was not about whose plugs are more braindead. I consider unpolarized plug as convenient and a safety feature, because polarized plugs are deadlier when miswired when they are assumed being correct, while devices with unpolarized plugs don't care and are safer.

Comment: That's a fair point, you're right. I've seen my fair share of miswired extension cords. Miswired outlet only once (but that was dramatic because Live was on the earth pin!) But we agree on the point that assuming a certain polarity is a bad idea.

Comment: Indeed, my cable modem power supply failed, dumping multiple amps down the cable sheath, melting the filter at the entrance...

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that earth-fault failure are a common type of dangerous failure, capacitors that connect active to earth must be Y-class.

Earth-fault failures are a type of dangerous failure (1) because earth is commonly connected to equipment cases, and (2) single fault earth-faults are often undetected.

If you have an isolated earth, that isn't attached to your equipment, or to any other equipment or anything, then you don't need Y-class capacitors. But no ordinary equipment can guarantee that it will never be connected to a shared earth.

Due to the fact that equipment cases (and plumbing, and conduits, and wiring errors) are often connected to ground, you need to use Y-class capacitors to connect to ground.